# search by date in mysql using dateformat

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I am getting date in date format `7-2-2014`

where as the mysql format is `2014-01-08 11:45:04`

I want to search the results using the format `7-2-2014` in  the table with table name `employees`

What is the query to be written in mysql ?

Comment: Please add the table description.

Comment: You have to give the data type as date(2014-01-08 09:33:33) in the query this will only give date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE '7-2-2014'= DATE_FORMAT(`date_col`,"%e-%c-%Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

This function used for convert the date format, set parameters as per your requirement
`select * from employees where DATE_FORMAT(date_from_table,'%d-%m-%Y')= your_date;`  see in this link this will help for you  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp